# How to share large Strings (150,000 characters) using intent in Android?

Tags: java, android, string, android-intent

My app shares a lengthy String. The following block of code works as long the String has near about **120,000** characters:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, out.getText().toString());
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
ResultActivity.this.startActivity(sendIntent);
System.out.println("started");
```

But as soon as the lenght exceeds, say 150,000 characters, the share intent does not start the required activity. I need a way to share large strings via similar technique.

There are no errors as `started` is printed in *LogCat* which indicated that the line `System.out.println("started");` has executed.

**UPDATE 1:** The exact length of the String is **129535** upto which I can trigger the sendIntent to start Sharing Activity.

**UPDATE 2:** If I'm not clear enough, I want to share the text (not as file) through this: [image]

Comment: At that size, I would recommend writing it to a file, using `FileProvider` and `EXTRA_STREAM` to share it.

Comment: would that be 65535 by chance? Have you considered splitting the string?

Comment: @Kaddath 65535(16-bit) would be the size, many messaging Apps such as **WhatsApp** accepts as the restriction limit for each message. And no, I can trigger the intent with **129535 character String** not more that that.

Comment: @CommonsWare I want these texts to be sent as a message, so I can't write it to a file and then share it.

Comment: That doesn’t make sense. What do you mean sent as a message and what does it have to do with writing to a file?

Comment: @MartinMarconcini how can it not make sense? I want to share the String via Intent to other Apps on my phone. Please read the question. If I had the choice to use File/Database I would have gone though it.

Comment: Since the Android Intent is behaving in unpredictable ways, mostly related to the string’s size, it’s clear you need an alternate solution. You question is “how to share ‘big’ strings with Android intents”. It appears that for a string *that size*, you have to use something else, but you keep insisting on using intents.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini, the alternative way is to truncate the string to send only first 65535 characters which is also the maximum length most of the messaging apps allow as a single message. Guess I have to settle with this workaround :D

Comment: Yes, if you have to send something that big, I’d split it. Good luck with that! :)

Comment: @KoushikShomChoudhury Did you get any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Intents have a data size limit of about 1 MB. The typical approach when dealing with large payloads is to put it a database flat file and then pass a database id to the file or URI to the flat file.

Then the receiving Activity would load the data from the Database or Flat file.

Comment: 150,000 characters would be around 146KB (which is miles less than 1MB) so data size limit is not exceeded. And as I mentioned in the question, I need **similar techniques**, i.e, **Share via Intent as String and not via File/Database**

Comment: Oh since it's not your app it may just be crashing or doing something wrong. If the receiving app doesn't support it then you might be stuck :(

Comment: The problem is with MIME type. It's sorted.